# Difference between limits $\infty$ and $+\infty$

Tags: limits, notation, infinity

Is there a difference between these two limits?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=+\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=\infty$$

Comment: $\infty$ generally denotes $+\infty$ much like $1$ and $+1$.

Comment: On the [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), for instance, there is only one point at infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference, it is just that sometimes it is good to be explicit, seeing sometimes you may have "$-\infty$" so the people use "$+\infty$" to make things very clear.

Answer (score 2):

No.

$+\infty$ and $\infty$ are syntactically equivalent and can be used interchangeably.